# Avoiding Stretching Stroke when Using CGContextScaleCTM

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a shape that I'm drawing in `drawRect` which is stored in a `CGMutablePathRef` (`shapeMutablePath`). Each time `drawRect` is called, the shape is stretched to fit the screen with a stroke border around it. I am wondering, how is it possible to draw the stroke border without also stretching it? ie stretching the `shapeMutablePath`, then drawing the stroke border around it so it's the same width every time it's drawn? I've tried changing the order of the scale and the add and draw path to no avail.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0000);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, DialogueTextViewLineWidth);

    CGContextScaleCTM (context, self.frame.size.width / self.shapeMutablePathWidth, self.frame.size.height / self.shapeMutablePathHeight);
    CGContextAddPath(context, self.shapeMutablePath);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of scaling the CTM and using the original path:

```
CGContextScaleCTM (context, self.frame.size.width / self.shapeMutablePathWidth, self.frame.size.height / self.shapeMutablePathHeight);
CGContextAddPath(context, self.shapeMutablePath);
```

... create a transformed path and use that instead:

```
CGAffineTransform trn = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.bounds.size.width / self.shapeMutablePathWidth, self.bounds.size.height / self.shapeMutablePathHeight);
CGPathRef transformedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(self.shapeMutablePath, &trn);
CGContextAddPath(context, transformedPath);
CGPathRelease(transformedPath);
```

This will fill and stroke the same (scaled) area but the transform will not affect the stroke width.

B.t.w. You would typically use the bounds, not the frame's size to calculate the scale.